How to configure unbound with --enable-systemd?
When trying to configure unbound with systemd enabled, unbound could not locate systemd.
$ ./configure --enable-systemd
...
...
...
checking for SYSTEMD... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libsystemd) were not met:

Package 'libsystemd', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables SYSTEMD_CFLAGS
and SYSTEMD_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.

However, systemd is present:
$ dpkg -l | grep systemd
ii  dbus-user-session                    1.14.10-1~deb12u1                       armhf        simple interprocess messaging system (systemd --user integration)
ii  libpam-systemd:armhf                 252.31-1~deb12u1                        armhf        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libsystemd-shared:armhf              252.31-1~deb12u1                        armhf        systemd shared private library
ii  libsystemd0:armhf                    252.31-1~deb12u1                        armhf        systemd utility library
ii  systemd                              252.31-1~deb12u1                        armhf        system and service manager
ii  systemd-resolved                     252.31-1~deb12u1                        armhf        systemd DNS resolver
ii  systemd-sysv                         252.31-1~deb12u1                        armhf        system and service manager - SysV compatibility symlinks
ii  systemd-timesyncd                    252.31-1~deb12u1                        armhf        minimalistic service to synchronize local time with NTP servers
$ ls /usr/lib/systemd
catalog            systemd-boot-check-no-failures  systemd-integritysetup        systemd-network-generator  systemd-shutdown             systemd-time-wait-sync           system-preset
network            systemd-cgroups-agent           systemd-journald              systemd-pcrphase           systemd-sleep                systemd-udevd                    system-shutdown
ntp-units.d        systemd-cryptsetup              systemd-localed               systemd-pstore             systemd-socket-proxyd        systemd-update-utmp              system-sleep
resolv.conf        systemd-fsck                    systemd-logind                systemd-quotacheck         systemd-sulogin-shell        systemd-user-runtime-dir         user
system             systemd-fsckd                   systemd-makefs                systemd-random-seed        systemd-sysctl               systemd-user-sessions            user-environment-generators
systemd            systemd-growfs                  systemd-measure               systemd-remount-fs         systemd-sysroot-fstab-check  systemd-veritysetup              user-generators
systemd-ac-power   systemd-hibernate-resume        systemd-modules-load          systemd-reply-password     systemd-sysv-install         systemd-volatile-root            user-preset
systemd-backlight  systemd-hostnamed               systemd-networkd              systemd-resolved           systemd-timedated            systemd-xdg-autostart-condition
systemd-binfmt     systemd-initctl                 systemd-networkd-wait-online  systemd-rfkill             systemd-timesyncd            system-generators

It seems that the systemd utility library package on this device is named libsystemd0 and not systemd. I have tried using
$ ./configure --enable-systemd SYSTEMD_LIBS=/usr/lib/systemd

but was returned with the same error msg as mentioned above.
Also,
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH

$ pkg-config --list-all 
libunbound                     unbound - Library with validating, recursive, and caching DNS resolver
libsodium                      libsodium - A modern and easy-to-use crypto library
libnsl                         libnsl - Library containing NIS functions using TI-RPC (IPv6 enabled)
expat                          expat - expat XML parser
libcrypt                       libxcrypt - Extended crypt library for DES, MD5, Blowfish and others
libtirpc                       libtirpc - Transport Independent RPC Library
openssl                        OpenSSL - Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries and tools
libssl                         OpenSSL-libssl - Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries
libxcrypt                      libxcrypt - Extended crypt library for DES, MD5, Blowfish and others
libcrypto                      OpenSSL-libcrypto - OpenSSL cryptography library
udev                           udev - udev
xkeyboard-config               XKeyboardConfig - X Keyboard configuration data
systemd                        systemd - systemd System and Service Manager
bash-completion                bash-completion - programmable completion for the bash shell
$ pkg-config --cflags systemd

$ pkg-config --cflags systemd0
Package systemd0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `systemd0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'systemd0', required by 'virtual:world', not found

How can I overcome this configuration issue?

If there's a -dev package, like libsystemd-dev, that's what you would need for compiling other software

@muru Thanks. sudo apt install libsystemd-dev resolved the configuration issue.

Since this package exists in Ubuntu, just use apt to get all dependencies in place if you want to build it yourself.
